# How to process this text

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have this file

```
86-22-63385835,63385836,63385933
86-0577-88609993,88835386 
86-21-58947602,58947603
0086-755-33186858,33186862,33186859
```

and i want result like this

```
86-22-63385835
86-22-63385836
86-22-63385933
86-0577-88609993
86-0577-88835386 
86-21-58947602
86-21-58947603
0086-755-33186858
0086-755-33186862
0086-755-33186859
```

anyone could help me .many thanks for that.

Comment: do i have any wrongs with my question ?

Comment: you need to shows your attempts. So that it won't get closed.

Comment: actually i dont have a clue now .

Comment: IMO, it's a fantastic question ...if you show your attempts, it would be more fantastic.

Comment: @AvinashRaj : could you help me ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could simply do this through awk,

```
$ awk -F[,-] '{var=$1"-"$2; for (i=3;i<=NF;i++){print var"-"$i}}' file
86-22-63385835
86-22-63385836
86-22-63385933
86-0577-88609993
86-0577-88835386 
86-21-58947602
86-21-58947603
0086-755-33186858
0086-755-33186862
0086-755-33186859
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer even my question is fool

Comment: @YOU next time, don't forget to show your attempts.

Answer (score 0):

This is your answer here.

```
awk -F "," '{print $1}'
```

In shortcut, awk divide all lines by "," and will print first word.

Comment: this show another result.

Comment: oh ,but how about the part after "," ,i need them too